# Fragment: Initialize the Loader

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

how I can use this (used in FragmentActivity):

```
//    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_CONTENT_SEARCH, args, this);
```

in my class

> public class LoaderActivity extends **Fragment** implements
>   LoaderCallbacks<(RESTLoader.RESTResponse>

Comment: Instead of `Fragment` use `FragmentActivity´

Comment: Yes I know but if I use the FragmentActivity I have an  other problem...I've the class public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity
implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks { and in the method onNavigationDrawerItemSelected{} I used fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, LoaderActivity.newInstance(position)).commit();

Comment: fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(....)used a Fragment and not FragmentActivity